# Does this query successfully find the first Monday of any given date's month?

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, dayofmonth

My server is configured such that Sunday is day 0 and Monday is day 1.  In order to find the first Monday of any given date's month, I have written this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,
                   - ((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [DATE])))) %7) - 1),
                  DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, [DATE]))))
```

Does this work as intended? Moreover, is there a better or more standard way? I find it very surprising that there's an `EOMONTH` function but nothing for the start of a month.

Comment: You may want to invest in a Calendar table.   This and so much more become easy

Comment: Aside from EOMONTH()  you also have DATEFROMPARTS()

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Would if I could. Mind, using the pathetic calendar table that we have to test the code in this question is an idea that I was very stupid not to have.

Comment: "Does this work as intended?" - you can verify this faster than we can.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select dateadd(day, (7 - datediff(day, -53690, mm.FirstOfMonth) % 7) % 7, mm.FirstOfMonth)
   From (Values (dateadd(month, datediff(month, 1, getdate()), 0))) As mm(FirstOfMonth)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer is working for monday. What for sun day, tues day or else.